# How to create Iphone package using Telerik App Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, open-source, telerik-appbuilder

i am using telerik app builder free account but 30 days trial expired,,, i have created android package but can't create iphone package...

> **Problem:**
>   Cannot find a valid Ad Hoc or Development provisioning profile that matches the application identifier you have set for your app. Click Options to manage your provisioning profiles or close this window, open the Properties dialog, and set a new application identifier for your app. This will cancel the current operation and you will need to run it again

Comment: should i have to use ios operating system such as IOS apple developer???? is there another way around bcause i have no source,,,,and also same for windows phones....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try intel xdk...or phonegap buil pakage....try to read full documentation on phonegap....because telerik will let you create "debug mode" apk for android not release one....**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add your iOS provisioning profile. There are a lot of docs about this on the AppBuilder site: http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/add-provisioning-profile

Comment: yeah i have read those articles before,,, i've found the solution i guess,,,, just setup free account using itunes and download telerik app builder and run application in that app...!!!i am trying to grab iphone from friend for testing pupose,,,,guess what,,i don't have android phone either...kind of 3rd world's poor developer eh??? thanks for the reply i appreciate that....i mean that...